# How can I transfer my World of Goo save file from Android to PC?

Tags: world-of-goo

I've been playing World of Goo lately on Android, and have gotten OCD on most of the maps. I'd like to finish off the rest of the maps on Steam so I can unlock the achievements there.

How can I transfer my World of Goo save file from Android to PC?

Answer (score 4):

You can't unfortunately. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Russ Whitchurch if this is the answer your looking for please accept it or tell me what I can do to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you most likely can do that. I managed to move the savegame the other way around (from linux to android) and it went well. You might need to have root access though.

I wrote this guide on transferring the linux savegame to android, but I imagne you can do it the other way around as long as you have the right folders in place and whatnot:

> Here's a short guide on how I did the transfer:
>
> 1. First of all, find your savefile on your computer. Detailed instructions on where you can find your savefile are in this link:
>      http://goofans.com/developers/game-file-formats/profile-file-format
> 2. Once you've found your savefile (which is named pers2.dat), copy it anywhere to your android phone.
> 3. Make a backup of your existing savefile just in case things goes haywire, its located on the phone at this folder:
>
> /datadata/com.twodboy.worldofgoofull/files/pers2.dat
>
> Though the phones console, I did the backup through these commands
>
> cd /datadata/com.twodboy.worldofgoofull/files/ mv pers2.dat
>   pers2.dat.backup
>
> 4. Copy your desktop savegame into /datadata/com.twodboy.worldofgoofull/files/ and make sure its named
>      pers2.dat (mind the lowercase).
>
> I did a transfer from my linux native world of goo savegame into the
>   phone and it worked fine, no need to change permissions, Ipad
>   decryption or anything. My phone is rooted and I did this whole thing
>   through webkeys web interface - however I doubt that rooting is
>   required in order to do this. This is one way of doing it and I'm sure
>   you will find an easier way.

The whole thread is located here:
http://goofans.com/forum/world-of-goo/general-discussion/3142

Do note that it was written five years ago, and that I can't help you more than whats written there :-)